# Develop Voip application for ONLY PC-to-PC call

Tags: voip, asterisk, sip

I want to create an application for ONLY Pc-to-Pc call.

Do I need server like asterisk or SIP ?

How can I get start ?

I will use P2P architecture.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any special software; you simply need a server with enough bandwidth. (Unless you use P2P and connect directly to the other machine)

You can get started by learning network programming and how to capture and encode audio.

Comment: You don't need a lot of bandwidth for a server. A simple SIP registrar is only queried to look up the current IP address of the party you are trying to call. The P2P SIP initiative is aiming to replace even this central service with a distributed hashtable.

Answer (score 1):

Well,

First you need to decide whether you are using Peer to peer architecture or a server based architecture.

If your application is extremely simple, you know the other party's IP address and recipient is in same subnet you may use P2P directly. Otherwise its easy to use a mechanism based on a centralized server.

You can still use P2P (Like skype does but it is more tricky)

Then you can think about your server and client applications. Server should listen for the clients (yes it is an opened port), accept the requests from clients and register them. It is the "Man in the middle" and it needs to route the packets to the correct destination.

The client is responsible to connect to the server (Authentication???), send recipient info to it and start sending voice data..

Comment: P2P like skype ;).
But I am very newbie.
How can I get start ?

Comment: I don't know whether I am tooo late. But if you are still interested on this you can have a look on Skype Protocol.

http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/~library/TR-repository/reports/reports-2004/cucs-039-04.pdf

This document will give you a sound understanding on the mechanism.